# Text on path not working from 4.1.2 to 4.0.3

Tags: java, android, text, android-canvas

I have started working on a game, and when the game ends it displays a board with the stats of the game. The winner's name, is drew on top of the board on an arch (using a class TextOnPath, which I will paste the code here). The text displays correctly in Android 4.1.2, but not the same thing happens to Android 4.0.3 or lower (I have attached images to show you this).

My questions is: what is wrong with my program? My min-SDK is 8 and I haven't used any new API introduces in JB. Please help me to find a solution.

This is my class(without the required methods for displaying the text):

```
public class TextOnPath extends View {
    private String winner = "Computer";
    private Path mArc;
    int viewHeight, viewWidth;
    private Paint mPaintText;
    public TextOnPath(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public TextOnPath(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int offset = 0;
        if (offset < 16)
            offset = (18 - winner.length()) * 11;
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(winner, mArc, offset, 40, mPaintText);

        invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
        viewWidth = xNew;
        viewHeight = yNew;
        Typeface chalk = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/Chalkduster.ttf");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mArc = new Path();
        int pad = 20;
        RectF oval = new RectF(pad, 0, viewWidth - pad, viewHeight);

        mArc.addArc(oval, -180, 180);
        mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        int textsize = R.dimen.chalk_text_size;
        System.err.println(textsize);
        mPaintText.setTextSize(30f);
        mPaintText.setTypeface(chalk);

        this.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

    }
```

Here I have posted 2 screenshots. 1'st one is from JB and the 2'nd one from ICS.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

drawTextOnPath() was not supported with hardware acceleration until Android 4.1. To work around this problem, simply set a software layer type on your View when running on Android < 4.1. Just call View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null). This will force software rendering and fix your problem.